# Jenkins job failing due to Android ADK license issue

Tags: android, jenkins, continuous-integration

When I try to run the android project on jenkins, am getting this error. This is not happening everytime. 50% of the time, its happening.

Any help would be appreciated

```
   build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3

   platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28

To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.

Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html



Using Android SDK: /opt/android-sdk

    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.initTarget(SdkHandler.java:194)

    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.ensureTargetSetup(BasePlugin.java:960)

    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:732)

    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$null$4(BasePlugin.java:670)

    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)

    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$5(BasePlugin.java:666)

    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)

    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)

    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)

    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)

    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)

    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)

    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)

    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)

    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)

    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)

    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)

    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)

    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:76)

    ... 81 more
```

Comment: _"To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager."_ Tried that?

Comment: Since it is on the remote machine, it doesn't have GUI. I need to do this using command line tools. I did that. Still facing the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some issue with android SDK. When we try to accept licenses through command-line, the problem was still araising
Finally, I added below commands as the first step in Jenkins.

```
echo y | sudo /opt/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;28.0.3"
echo y | sudo /opt/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-28"
```

Then it worked. The first time when I ran the job, it accepted the licenses. I removed the command and ran it. It's working perfectly now